# Select item WebBrowser C#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have:

```
<select name='petbet'><option value='1'>Speedy</option><option value='2'>Snuffles</option><option value='3'>Sneak</option><option value='4'>Snow</option><option value='5'>Slowww</option></select>
```

I try:

```
            var test22 = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select").Count;
            webBrowser2.Document.Forms[0].SetAttribute("value", "3");
```

In this case I don't have ID so I can't get it with ID, but also I have problem when I try with TagName. Any Solution?

Comment: Do you find the control? Are you having difficulty setting the select?

Answer (score 1):

You can get `HtmlElement` by `name` attribute or `InnerText` property if you set unique names to them.

For example:

```
HtmlElementCollection selectElements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select");
HtmlElement select = selectElements.Cast<HtmlElement>().FirstOrDefault(s => s.GetAttribute("name") == "petbet");
HtmlElementCollection optionElements = select.GetElementsByTagName("option");
HtmlElement option = optionElements.Cast<HtmlElement>().FirstOrDefault(o => o.InnerText == "Sneak");
```